# Shuffle a matrix using specified indexes in Excel?

Tags: excel

My goal is to shuffle a matrix using a specified matrix of indexes.

For example, let's say this is my input matrix:

```
A B C
D E F
G H I
```

Now I want to shuffle my input matrix. But not in a random way, I want to use a custom set of indexes (0, 1, 2 etc.) that represent the final order of my matrix. Let's say this is the matrix of indexes:

```
5 3 8
1 0 4
2 7 6
```

The resulting matrix should be:

```
F D I
B A E
C H G
```

since `A` was in position `0`, `B` was in position `1` etc.
I'm looking for the formula that I should insert in each cell of the resulting matrix. I tried `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions but I'm not sure this is the right way.

Comment: What have you tried? You can easily use INDEX on a named column-wise range containing your letters to do this and simply + 1 to account for 0  being A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use quotient/mod to get row and column

```
=INDEX($A$1:$C$3,QUOTIENT(E1,3)+1,MOD(E1,3)+1)
```

[image]

You could make it more general if you wanted to.

Comment: Fine, just show me up.....I will just slink into my corner. :)

Comment: I sometimes put in a naive answer in the expectation of having it knocked down, so this would be an exception. But don't worry, I don't think I will catch you up any time soon :-)